# Is it possible to create and stop actors outside of their thread

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka

I'd like to build actor hierarchy from outside of actor system. The hierarchy is dynamically changed according to passed description. Description is a tree holding `Props` objects. I prefer to separate code that reconfigures actor hierarchy from actor class. So actors should be created and stopped outside an actor thread.

Simplified example:

```
val system = ActorSystem("example")
val actor1 = system.actorOf[prop1, "1"]
val actor2 = actor1.context.actorOf[prop2, "2"]
```

I wonder how to extract context from an actor. And even if I provide appropriate method, context is said to be valid only inside actor. I'd like to avoid creating mix-in that would delegate spawning children to outside.

I write a simple demonstration of how can extractor context exposing may be implemented.

```
trait Holder {
  var factory : Option[ActorRefFactory] = None
  val factoryLock = new Object
  val props : Props // oftype ExposedActor, but Props lacks type parametrization
  val parent : Holder

  def create(props : Props, name : String) : ActorRef =
    factoryLock synchronized {
      factory.map( _.actorOf(props, name) ).get
    }
  val actorRef = parent.create(props, "ugly")
}

trait ExposedActor extends Actor {
  val holder : Holder
  override def preStart() {
    super.preStart()
    holder.factoryLock.synchronized {
      holder.factory = Some(context)
    }
  }
}
```

But there is a drawback: I need to mix the `ExposedActor` trait in all actors

Comment: this should not be possible, because `system.actorOf` returns an `ActorRef` which does not give you access to the internals of an `Actor`. Since starting children entails changing the internal state of an `Actor` it is only possible from within the `Actor`.

Comment: I know that `ActorRef` have no `context` method. That is why I've wrote "I wonder how to extract context from an actor". May be some reflection tricks would be useful

Comment: This won't help you either because the `Actor` might be started outside of your JVM on a completely different machine. Furthermore, I assume that you want your parent to supervise the children. Then it should at least know how to deal with failures (e.g. restarting the children, escalating the errors). At this point, you would have to execute some logic from within the actor which affects the actor hierarchy.

Comment: Trying to spawn actors from outside of the system is not compatible with the Akka way of doing things. If you can be clearer about your end goal, maybe someone can answer on how best to achieve it without needing to start actors that way.

Comment: Added example code to the question

Comment: I would have a top-level actor to which I can pass the configuration data (for the Props tree) as a message, and it would be responsible for creating/destroying the required tree of actors under it.

Comment: that tree may be modified dynamically. Some leafs added, some removed, branch moved from one place to another. At that case before removing actors should be stopped and after attaching - recreated from props and parent

Comment: @ayvango That should all be maintainable by sending appropriate messages to the governing top-level actor.

Comment: And how can it get context from arbitrary child? It should contain sub-sub-sub actors. And if it would use own `actorContext` it would be able to create only sub-actors

Comment: @ayvango Two ways I can think of: 1) The governing actor just sends messages to lower-level actors to get them to create/destroy their children (and, for example, reply with the ref of the created child actor for the govenor to track), or 2) create all actors as direct children of the governing actor and manage the "tree" through passing refs to the actors to inform them of who they should consider "above" or "below" them.

Comment: 1) that would make hard to use become/unbecome and FSM actors. Ability to create children from message is needed to be mixed in each state

Comment: If you want to dynamically change the actor hierarchy then you should use Shadowland's solution of passing create/modify/destroy messages down the hierarchy, even if it means adding mixins.  If you want to muck with the actor internals from outside of the actor system then you shouldn't be using actors.

Comment: And what is the proper way to construct mix-in in akka? That is compatible with things like become/unbecome